# How to connect Kindle Fire HDX for debugging over USB with ADB

Tags: android, adb, kindle-fire

I have a kindle fire HDX 7.0 (third generation), and am trying to connect it for development using adb.

I am running OSX version 10.9.3, and have not been able to connect via adb irrespective of what i try.

I have tried suggestions around adding a vendor id for amazon - 0x1949
or using the command android update adb.

What can be done, any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Amazon started to hide the developer options on it's newer devices. You need to expose these in order to connect to USB for debugging. On my Kindle Fire HDX 8.9", this is what worked for me.

Go to:

```
Settings->Device Options
```

Scroll down to the Serial Number.  Start to slowly tap on the serial number. Unlike other devices, you should only have to do it a few times. The Developer Options should become exposed below the option to reset to factory defaults.

Once exposed, select Developer Options. Scroll down to "Enable ADB" and switch this option to ON. You should now be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

The following instructions I used with Windows 7, but should be similar across other platforms. With debugging mode enabled on your device (goto settings tap serial number multiple times and then ensure you have enabled ADB mode).

Then open Androids SDK Manager.exe
"Goto Tools - Manage Add On Sites" in the menu
Click the "User Defined Sites" tab.
Add the following entry: "http://kindle-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/addon.xml"
Close these menus

Now, still in SDK Manager, go towards the bottom of your list of packages and find the "Kindle Fire USB Driver".  Ensure it is checked and install packages.  It's also prudent to install the other suggested packages, I also had the older API21 FWIW, but this may no longer be necessary.

In Windows, navigate to the installation of your Android SDK, e.g. c:\Android\sdk
Navigate to the folder "Android\sdk\extras\amazon\kindle_fire_usb_driver"
Open "KindleDrivers.exe" and follow the onscreen prompts to install/reinstall the device.
Eventually the driver will be installed (if you check in Windows Device Manager you should see the driver under Kindle Fire).

Now plugin your Fire HDX.  You may need to give permission on the tablet for your PC to use the device for debugging.

At that point, you should now be able to debug as normal.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.However, the SDK location has changed in the newer versions of Android Studio. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is usb debugging on? :)

Sometimes certain devices I'm testing with don't appear until I kill adb with su permissions. You could also try switching between MTP and PTP.

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb devices
```

Comment: Kindle fire does not expose this mode, and I tried sudo as well.. somehow just does not work. Any other devices works out of the box its just kindle fire hdx. Dont really know the root cause